# Score gained since last edit

Tags: feature-request, voting

New users usually ask/commit horrible questions/answers, and some of them will edit their posts to make them better, guided by the comments below the post. However, many downvotes might have already been casted then, and few of them would be withdrawn in the end.

So, will it be better to have a "Score gained since last edit" section enclosed in parentheses for every question? Maybe it'll be something like **Score: -5(+2)**?

Comment: This wouldn't be a half bad idea to highlight good edits (although it likely shouldn't be displayed in the total score.)

Answer (score 8):

Most casual users of Stack Overflow won't understand why there's more than one number. I think your proposal will therefore simply cause confusion.

If you really do want to know you can always look at the [post's timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/319837/timeline).

Comment: Please tell me how to get to the timelines, I can only get urls such as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319837/5399734 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319837/score-gained-since-last-edit/319838#319838

Comment: @sunqingyao There is no link on the page to access the timeline, you need to write the URL by hand. Or [install a user-script](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) that adds it. A bit self-promoting but I wrote one exactly for that [here](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts/blob/master/showtimeline.user.js).